# How do you write the number 180 in Chinese: 一百八十 or 一八零?

Tags: difference, number

How do you write the number 180 in Chinese?

I have tried searched on google and I believe it is 一百八十 but some people are telling me it is 一八零 I have heard from multiple people on each side. I would just like confirmation on how it generally it is written from someone who is more knowledgable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一百八十 is a counting number, e.g. 一百八十元 ($180)/ 一百八十號(#180)

一八零 is a digital identity number, e.g. part of a serial number or phone number

If a number is referring to an amount or order that can be counted, use 一百八十

If a number is referring to a digital identity, use
一八零 (e.g. serial number, phone number)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct, but used in different contexts.  In any case, for writing, we'd almost always just write the numbers 180.

一百八十 (or just 一百八 for short) is the literal "one hundred and eighty"; it's used in sentences such as:

> 我买了**一百八十**个苹果。 (I bought 180 apples);
> **一百八**一斤。 (180 per half-kilo).

一八零 just lists out the numerals "one eight zero" (where 一 might be pronounced yāo depending on dialect and personal preferences), which might be used as follows:

> 我的手机号码是**一八零**……。 (My phone number is 180...)
> 这家公司创始于**一八零**年。  (This company was founded in the year 180.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Tang Ho♦ and Becky 李蓓♦ are right, and the numeral form is also used to describe height.

The 183cm（一米八三） has the short form 一八三(yāo and yī both ok).

There is a recently popular joke on Chinese Internet: Some people are so proud of their height that they never miss a chance to show off it. So you can often  see username like "张三(183.5cm" (it is high enough in Asia) . A girl and a boy are talking about the school exam score, the girl says “我考了90分，你多高？”(My score is ..., and how about you?), the boy answers “一八三”(Obviously not a score).

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used at any place if 180 means one hundred and eighty. But "一百八十" is more official than "一八零".

When you use 180 in phone numbers, it does not mean 一百八十 (one hundred and eighty) because it is used with other numbers like you can not say 780 as senven and eighty or senventy eight and zero.